# html5 canvas adding drag and drop to images drawn to the canvas

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

I have a webpage with an HTML5 canvas which I'm using to display a number of images as well as four 'description boxes' on the canvas.

The intention is that users will be able to drag and drop the images to their matching description boxes, however, I'm having a bit of trouble getting the dragging and dropping working.

The function I've written to add the drag and drop functionality is based on the tutorial I found at this page: http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful

Obviously, I altered the code slightly, as I don't want to do everything suggested in the tutorial, and because I'm drawing images (not shapes) to the canvas. However, when viewing my page in the browser although all of the images are displayed on the canvas, the drag and drop functionality has not been added along with the new JavaScript file I've written based on that tutorial.

I'm not getting any errors in the Firebug console, and the page is displaying exactly as it was before I added the new JS function.

Can anyone spot what I'm missing?

My HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src = "kinetic.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<title>Home</title>

<script src = "drawLevelOneElements.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "layers&analytics.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "startGameDrawGameElementsDrawStartButton.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "interaction.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "dragAndDrop.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>


</head>

<body onLoad="startGame()">

<section hidden>
<img id="StartButton" src="StartButton.png" alt="Start Button" width="179" height="180" href="javascript:drawLevelOneElements();"/>
</section>

    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>The purpose of this website is to teach users the basic principles of running a business by playing the game below. <br /><br /></p>

    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="1000" height="500" style="border:1px solid">
    Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>

    <br /><br />
    <p>Use this paragraph to enter text that provides the user with instructions for how to play the game. <br />
        Update the instructions so that they're appropriate to whatever level the user is currently playing.</p>

<script src = "layers&analytics.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "startGameDrawGameElementsDrawStartButton.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "variables&preloadingImages.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "drawLevelOneElements.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "interaction.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script src = "variables&preloadingImages.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

All of the script tags at the bottom of the page (except the last one) are actually commented out in my file, I just had to remove the comment to get it to display in a code block on here.

The javaScript I've added for the drag and drop functionality is:

```
function canvasState(myGameCanvas){

var bounding_box = myGameCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var mouseX = (mouse_event.clientX-bounding_box.left) * (myGameCanvas.width/bouding_box.width);
var mouseY = (mouse_event.clientY-bounding_box.top) * (myGameCanvas.height/bounding_box.height);
var pixels = context.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1);

this.valid = false; /*When set to true, the canvas will redraw everything */
this.allImagesArray; /*This is the array holding all of the images to be drawn */
this.dragging = false; /*Keep track of when the current selected object is being dragged */
this.selection = null;
this.dragOffX = 0; /*See mousedown and mousemove events for explanation */
this.dragOffY = 0;

this.interval = 30; /*This variable will be used to determine how often the draw method is called. */

/*Save a reference to the canvasState so that I'm still using this particular canvasState. */
var myState = this;

/*This stops double clicking on the canvas selecting text on the canvas */
myGameCanvas.addEventListener('selectstart', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); return false; }, false);
/*Up, down and move are for dragging */
myGameCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
    var mX = mouse.x;
    var mY = mouse.y;
    var allImages = myState.allImagesArray;
    var NoOfImages = allImages.length;
    for (var i = 1-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(allImages[i].contains(mX, mY)){
            var mySelection = allImages[i];
            /*Keep track of where in the object was clicked, so that it can be 
                moved smoothly (see mousemove) */
            myState.dragOffX = mX - mySelection.x;
            myState.dragOffY = mY - mySelection.y;
            myState.dragging = true;
            myState.selection = mySelection;
            myState.valid = false;
            return;
        }
    }
    /*If the code hasn't returned, it means that nothing has been selected.
    If there was an object selected, then deselect it. */
    if (myState.selection){
        myState.selection = null;
        myState.valid = false; /*Need to clear the old selection border */

    }
}, true);

/*This event checks to see if the dragging flag has been set to true. If it has, it gets the
current mouse position and moves the selected object to that position, remembering the offset
where it was selected. If the dragging flag is false, the event does nothing. */
myGameCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    if(myState.dragging){
        var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
        /*I don't want to drag the object by its top left corner, I want to drag from where the
        object was clicked. That's why I saved the offset and use it here. */
        myState.selection.x = mouse.x - myState.dragOffX;
        myState.selection.y = mouse.y - myState.dragOffY;
        myState.valid = false; /*Something's dragging, so I must redraw */
    }
}, true);

/*All the mouseup event has to do is update the canvas state so that it is no longer dragging.
So, once the mouse button is lifted, the mousemove event should be back to doing nothing. */
myGameCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
    myState.dragging = false;
}, true);

setInterval(function(){ myState.draw(); }, myState.interval);

canvasState.prototype.draw = function(){
    /*If the state is invalid,redraw and validate. */
    if (!this.valid){
        var context = this.context;
        var images = this.images;
        this.clear();

        /*Redraw the game elements here */
        drawLevelOneElements();
    }
}


}
```

Code for dragAndDrop.js:

```
function canvasState(myGameCanvas){

var bounding_box = myGameCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var mouseX = (mouse_event.clientX-bounding_box.left) * (myGameCanvas.width/bouding_box.width);
var mouseY = (mouse_event.clientY-bounding_box.top) * (myGameCanvas.height/bounding_box.height);
var pixels = context.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1);

this.valid = false; /*When set to true, the canvas will redraw everything */
this.allImagesArray; /*This is the array holding all of the images to be drawn */
this.dragging = false; /*Keep track of when the current selected object is being dragged */
this.selection = null;
this.dragOffX = 0; /*See mousedown and mousemove events for explanation */
this.dragOffY = 0;

this.interval = 30; /*This variable will be used to determine how often the draw method is called. */

/*Save a reference to the canvasState so that I'm still using this particular canvasState. */
var myState = this;

/*This stops double clicking on the canvas selecting text on the canvas */
myGameCanvas.addEventListener('selectstart', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); return false; }, false);
console.log("Event Listener 'selectstart' added to canvas.");
/*Up, down and move are for dragging */
myGameCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    console.log("Event Listener 'mousedown' added to canvas");
    var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
    var mX = mouse.x;
    var mY = mouse.y;
    var allImages = myState.allImagesArray;
    var NoOfImages = allImages.length;
    for (var i = 1-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(allImages[i].contains(mX, mY)){
            var mySelection = allImages[i];
            /*Keep track of where in the object was clicked, so that it can be 
                moved smoothly (see mousemove) */
            myState.dragOffX = mX - mySelection.x;
            myState.dragOffY = mY - mySelection.y;
            myState.dragging = true;
            myState.selection = mySelection;
            myState.valid = false;
            return;
        }
    }
    /*If the code hasn't returned, it means that nothing has been selected.
    If there was an object selected, then deselect it. */
    if (myState.selection){
        myState.selection = null;
        myState.valid = false; /*Need to clear the old selection border */

    }
}, true);

/*This event checks to see if the dragging flag has been set to true. If it has, it gets the
current mouse position and moves the selected object to that position, remembering the offset
where it was selected. If the dragging flag is false, the event does nothing. */
myGameCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    console.log("Event listener 'mousemove' added to canvas.");
    if(myState.dragging){
        var mouse = myState.getMouse(e);
        /*I don't want to drag the object by its top left corner, I want to drag from where the
        object was clicked. That's why I saved the offset and use it here. */
        myState.selection.x = mouse.x - myState.dragOffX;
        myState.selection.y = mouse.y - myState.dragOffY;
        myState.valid = false; /*Something's dragging, so I must redraw */
    }
}, true);

/*All the mouseup event has to do is update the canvas state so that it is no longer dragging.
So, once the mouse button is lifted, the mousemove event should be back to doing nothing. */
myGameCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
    console.log("Event listener 'mouseup' added to canvas.");
    myState.dragging = false;
}, true);

setInterval(function(){ myState.draw(); }, myState.interval);

canvasState.prototype.draw = function(){
    /*If the state is invalid,redraw and validate. */
    if (!this.valid){
        var context = this.context;
        var images = this.images;
        this.clear();

        /*Redraw the game elements here */
        drawLevelOneElements();
    }
}


}
```

Code for drawLevelOneElements.js: (this now includes the call to canvasState(); )

```
function drawLevelOneElements(){
            /*First, clear the canvas */ 
            context.clearRect(0, 0, myGameCanvas.width, myGameCanvas.height);
            /*This line clears all of the elements that were previously drawn on the canvas. */
            /*Then redraw the game elements */
            drawGameElements(); 
            /*Call the function to enable drag and drop */
            canvasState(document.getElementById('gameCanvas'));

            /*Create the four description areas, and place them near the bottom of the canvas */
            /*Create boxes with rounded corners for the description areas */
            CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawDescriptionArea = function(x, y, width, height, radius, stroke){
                if(typeof stroke == "undefined" ){
                    stroke = true;
                }
                if(typeof radius === "undefined"){
                    radius = 5;
                }
                this.beginPath();
                this.moveTo(x + radius, y);
                this.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
                this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
                this.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
                this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
                this.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
                this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
                this.lineTo(x, y + radius);
                this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
                this.closePath();
                if(stroke){
                    context.stroke();
                }
            }

            context.drawDescriptionArea(70, 400, 120, 70);
            context.font = '25pt Calibri';
            context.strokeText('Asset', 90, 440);

            context.drawDescriptionArea(300, 400, 120, 70);
            context.strokeText('Liability', 310, 440);

            context.drawDescriptionArea(540, 400, 120, 70);
            context.strokeText('Income', 550, 440);

            context.drawDescriptionArea(750, 400, 180, 70);
            context.strokeText('Expenditure', 760, 440);

            /*Now draw the images to the canvas */
            /*First, create variables for the x & y coordinates of the image that will be drawn.
                the x & y coordinates should hold random numbers, so that the images will be 
                drawn in random locations on the canvas.*/
                var imageX = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
                var imageY = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);

                /*Create a 'table' of positions that the images will be drawn to */
                var imagePositionsX = [20, 80, 140, 200, 260, 320, 380, 440, 500, 560];
                var imagePositionsY = [20, 60, 100, 140, 180, 220, 260, 300, 340, 380];

            /*Draw all images from assetsImageArray */
            /*Use a while loop to loop through the array, get each item and draw it. */
            var arrayIteration = 0;
            console.log('All Images Array length: ' + allImagesArray.length); /*Display the length of the array in the console, to check it's holding the correct number of images. */
            while(arrayIteration < allImagesArray.length){
                var randomPositionX = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
                var randomPositionY = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
                context.drawImage(allImagesArray[arrayIteration], imageX, imageY, 50, 50);
                console.log(arrayIteration); /*Display the current array position that's being drawn */
                arrayIteration = arrayIteration+1;
                /*Now try changing the values of imageX & imageY so that the next image is drawn to a 
                    different location*/
                imageX = imagePositionsX[randomPositionX];  /* imageX+(Math.floor(Math.random()*100)); */
                imageY = imagePositionsY[randomPositionY];  /* imageY+(Math.floor(Math.random()*100));  */

            }

        }
```

Comment: do any of the listeners fire? put some alerts in them or log to the console.

Comment: Apparently not... I added a console.log beneath each of the `addEventListener` lines, but none of those messages were displayed in the console- any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is the canvasState() function even called? if it is, are you passing in the correct argument for myGameCanvas?

Comment: I've included the JS file with the canvasState() function in my HTML using a 'scipt src' line, but it doesn't look like it's being called... how do I make it be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conclusion to the comments, I can answer you this: Somewhere within your code, you have to call the canvasState() function, it's not enough just to define it. Where you must call it largely depends on when you need it's functionality. By example, if you want to set up the drag and drop functionality when the page loads, you have an event handler for the body's load event:

```
<body onLoad="startGame()">
```

Somewhere in the startGame() function's code, you would call canvasState(). If you you want it when StartButton is pressed, you should call it from within the drawLevelOneElements() function. Since you were following a tutorial, the order in which things happen might matter, so there might be a particular place where you need to call your function.

One more advice. Because you seem to be learning, start with the basics and work your way up with a deep understanding of what you learned up to that point, don't just follow random tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
 I've done what you suggested, and included a call to canvasState() within my drawLevelOneElements() function, however, I'm now getting a Firebug error that says "myGameCanvas is undefined".

Comment: you should call it like this: `canvasState(document.getElementById('gameCanvas'))` .

Comment: Ah Ok, thanks. I added in a couple of other JS files that are being used, but your last comment seems to have sorted that problem- thanks very much!

Comment: I'm now getting another error saying, "mouse_event" is not defined for my dragAndDrop.js file... any idea why this is?

Comment: The line it's complaining about is line 11:  `var mouseX = (mouse_event.clientX-bounding_box.left) * (myGameCanvas.width/bouding_box.width);`

Comment: well, mouse_event is not defined at that point, it just seems like you copy / pasted those lines from somewhere else. they look like they belong to one of the event handlers. you should really take my second advice :)

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested there, so I now have the line `canvasState(document.getElementById('gameCanvas'));` , but I'm still getting the "mouse_event is not defined" error in the Firebug console. Any other ideas? Thanks for your help with this- it's really appreciated!